# Named and optional parameters in MonoDevelop

Tags: xamarin.ios, monodevelop

I'm trying to use named and/or optional parameters in MonoTouch but it seems that MonoDevelop doesn't like that.

I have a constructor like this:

```
public SomeAttribute ( string label, string detail, bool custom = false )
{
    //...
}
```

While that compiles just fine, MonoDevelop underlines the line in red, signalizing a compiler error (which doesn't occur though). Is there some reason why this happens, and can I somehow update MonoDevelop to not see this as a error?

I'm using MonoDevelop 2.4.2 (on Mac). Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrade to MonoDevelop 2.6 beta 1.